# How do I write color text to the Visual Studio output window from c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to write color text to the Visual Studio output window from c#. I want to output red code from my unit tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually there are extensions for that. I use the lite (free) version of [VSCommands for Visual Studio 2010](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d491911d-97f3-4cf6-87b0-6a2882120acf). With the Pro version a regex could be set to make the colouring. In the lite version I add "warning" text to the debug message and it is written in light brown.

Answer (score 7):

I found this question while trying to figure out why some of the lines of text in my Visual Studio 2017 Output window are colored red, and how I could accomplish the same thing.

I found that I was able to get red text by writing out a line which included:

- an instance of "`Error:`" (Error, colon, followed by a space)
- (other characters can go here)
- another instance of "`Error:`" (Error, colon, followed by a space)
- (other characters can go here)
- followed by 1 instance of "`Error *`" (Error, followed by a space and then some other character)
- (other characters can go here)

An example:

```
Debug.WriteLine("Error: This line will be red Error: Error Jeff");
```

Answer (score 7):

In addition to Jeff Roe I've managed to get this:

**Warnings:** `Console.WriteLine($"Warning: Warning '{message}'");`

**Errors:** `Console.WriteLine($"Error: Error '{message}'");`

[image]

*Sadly I could not figure out how to get green output. 
If any1 could add this I would be super happy !*

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, the output window in Visual Studio is a "simple textbox" type control that doesn't support colored text.

Comment: If we print a bunch of dashes, these show up green. `Debug.WriteLine(new string('-', 50));`

Comment: At least five dashes actually

Answer (score -2):

```
SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, x)
```

Where k is an integer color value and hConsole is a standard output handle.

[More Here - easier commands](http://dotnetperls.com/console-color)

Comment: That only affects a Console window (i.e., a DOS command prompt), not the Visual Studio output window.

Answer (score -2):

**Edited**
The code below works to display output in Windows Console, not to Visual Studio Output window (thanks @AnthonyLambert  for correcting me).

```
 Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta; //Choose from the Enum
 Console.WriteLine("This message is to be in Magenta!");
 Console.ResetColor();//Reset to default
```

Comment: I don't think this works in the Visual Studio Output window.