# How to highlight a text in Visual Studio output window?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, vsix

I'm developing a VSIX and I need to write some information to Visual Studio output window. So, I use the approach that is described here - [How do I write to the Visual Studio Output Window in My Custom Tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094366/how-do-i-write-to-the-visual-studio-output-window-in-my-custom-tool)

Now, I'd like to highlight an output text if something goes wrong. It should be like this:

[image]

Unfortunately, I have not found any useful information about it yet.

Comment: You might try ` VSColorOutput` extension

Comment: @Jeroen van Langen, I should implement the same functionality like VSColorOutput in my VSIX, but not use this extension. But I can research their code in github...

Comment: check it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31588400/visual-studio-2015-output-window-highlight-effect

Comment: @Xawery Wiśniowiecki, thanks, but my question isn't related to VSColorOutput extension.

Comment: review this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426609/how-do-i-write-color-text-to-the-visual-studio-output-window-from-c